# Re-assign values to new object, deep clone, better solution?

Tags: java

I have an object that contains several fields (ints, Strings, etc) but also a HashMap and an ArrayList. This objects holds parameters used to later build a database query but there are times when I need to re-use all of the exact same parameters for an additional query, except for different items in the ArrayList.

I've noticed that when I change what's in the array list, it always changes the original object. I've figured out how to make a shallow copy by overriding the clone() method but the array list always remains shared by any copy of the object. Before diving into deep copies and the like I think I need advice on whether that's the best route.

Here's an example of the object I need to find a way to duplicate.

```
public class QueryParameters implements Cloneable {

    protected HashMap<String,String> foundArgs = new HashMap<String,String>();
    protected ArrayList<ActionType> action_types = new ArrayList<ActionType>();

    protected String lookup_type = "lookup";
    protected Location loc;
    protected Vector player_location;
    protected int id = 0;
    protected int radius;
    protected boolean allow_no_radius = false;
    protected String player;
    protected String world;
    protected String time;
    protected String entity;
    protected String block;
    // ... lots of getters/setters
}
```

I could always make a new instance and use getters/setters to transfer the data but that feels too verbose to me - there are about 15 fields I'd have to copy over and if I ever add new ones I'd need to remember to add them here.

What's the best way for me to obtain a new instance/clone so that changes to `action_types` doesn't affect the original object

Comment: Just create a copy constructor?

Comment: You can always use the trick where you serialise and deserialise the object in `clone()`. That guarantees a complete deep clone, with the caveat that controlling the process is fiddlier.

Comment: How does that affect performance? I would imagine it'd be faster for me to just create a new instance and assign the values from the old instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest writing a clone method that uses super.clone() to copy most of the fields, and then replaces the ArrayList in the clone. Something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QueryParameters implements Cloneable {
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "QueryParameters [action_types=" + action_types + ", otherData="
        + otherData + "]";
  }

  protected ArrayList<String> action_types = new ArrayList<String>();
  protected String otherData;

  @Override
  public QueryParameters clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    QueryParameters cloned = (QueryParameters) super.clone();
    cloned.action_types = new ArrayList<String>(action_types);
    return cloned;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    QueryParameters test = new QueryParameters();
    test.otherData = "a field";
    test.action_types.add("xyzzy");
    test.action_types.add("abcde");
    System.out.println("Original: " + test);
    QueryParameters clone = test.clone();
    clone.action_types.add("A new action type");
    System.out.println("Modified clone: " + clone);
    System.out.println("Original after clone modification: " + test);
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the easiest to implement with my current code organization and so far tests indicate that it works as desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use getters and setters if you "clone your own class". A constructor like this maybe?

```
private QueryParameter(QueryParameter other)
{
    foundArgs = new HashMap<String, String>(other.foundArgs);
    action_types = new ArrayList<ActionType>(other.action_types);
    // etc
}

// As a static method, or
public static QueryParameter copyOf(QueryParameter other)
{
    return new QueryParameter(other);
}

// as an instance method
public QueryParameter copy()
{
    return new QueryParameter(this);
}
```

This is one solution among many...

Comment: I think the `// etc` part is what the OP wanted to avoid. ("I could always make a new instance and use getters/setters to transfer the data but that feels too verbose to me")

Comment: @millimoose from my understanding the OP wanted to create a new instance and then assign this new instance's fields from the code itself. I therefore proposed a solution which would allow him not do that. At least that is how I understand the initial question.

Comment: No matter where they are, I'd prefer to avoid assigning everything in the object over again. I'll do that if it's the best option for performance, etc but I tend to like not listing out everything. My original class has no constructor as-is, things are just set externally using setters.

Comment: Well, it is certainly faster than using setters/getters, and it hides all the complexity too (and you don't need to implement `Cloneable` as an added bonus). Now, you can always `.clone()` of course, as suggested by @PatriciaShanahan.